# The water and light in Genesis 1:1-3

Tags: genesis, creation, birth-of-jesus

The Nicene Creed says that Jesus was "begotten before the ages" (begotten not made).

Col 1:15 calls Jesus the ""Firstborn of all creation," 
Proverbs 8:22 says that, referring to wisdom, it was brought forth (NIV) as the first work of God,

Putting it all together, these passages could all point to the water and light of Genesis 1:1-3.

A birth requires something that **already exists** in order to be brought forth from within another.  So the term "firstborn" does not in and of itself mean "first-created."  The birth of an only begotten Son before the ages, could come after a **"breaking of water"** (which the water breaks even before natural birth) and the water could even be **living water**, hence the water or living water, is present, then the Light which comes out of the Father, the Light of the World, the only begotten Son, is brought forth, i.e. born.

"Let there be Light" was said before day one was fully established. Couldn't that be an announcement of the begetting and not an order to be carried out? This event of a begetting could even be of a "Big Bang" quantum type of Light from Light situation.

Sorry if this is confusing. Before you tell me that the only begotten Son was not born, just pre-eminent by the term "Firstborn", I ask you to reconsider. Some of the early church fathers refer to Jesus as the "Begotten God" and the Father as the "Unbegotten God" and do recognize the Son as a true, yet eternal offspring, btw.

Comment: Welcome, Living Water. Your comments provide lots of information / research, showing your view. However, you have not actually asked a question! The one Q in the comments only requires a 'Yes' or 'No' response. This site is not for exchanges of personal views but to ask specific Qs in order to obtain specific answers. Please formulate a particular Q addressed to a particular group. Do take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  as we are different to other sites.

Comment: You might find these articles helpful: https://www.gotquestions.org/was-Jesus-created.html https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-the-Creator.html

Comment: Thank you Cerulean Chelonia. I agree with most of what is said in the links. I believe Jesus has always existed but was not begotten before He was begotten. I believe He was begotten before creation and that was announced on day one of creation and that the process of His begetting is sigb

Comment: Thank you!I agree with most of what is said in the links. I believe Jesus has always existed but was not actually born until just before creation. I believe He was born before creation and that was announced on day one as “Let there be Light” and that the process of His birth is significant as to why there was water and matter before “Let there be light” was announced. In a natural birth, water is released that contains nutrients and stem cells, etc. Is there a connection between the birth/begetting of the Son to the water and unformed earth that exists in Genesis 1:1-3. Think amniotic fluid.

Comment: I rewrote the first follow up comment because it posted before I was finished and then tried to edit it and it took too long, so just read the second comment, I think it is more clearly written. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: These theologies were not as concrete in the early church as they are today. Without a framework to answer this under, any answer would just be the opinion of the answerer.

Comment: @LivingWater I can answer your question but you need to modify it. For intro you can find the "water" or "amniotic fluid" in Genesis1:2 as it pertains to the Mystery of Incarnation. The Holy Spirit hovers the waters, means the Holy Spirit hovers the waters of the pure womb of Mary. And only after this verse, follows the actual creation "Let there be LIght". Genesis:1:1 or "Bereshit" has a coded secret, it is the blueprint of salvation. I can answer this but there's a great possibility that your question will be put to hold.

Comment: Are you a Kabbalist? Your “question” is a mixture of many different creeds, this is typified by cognitive dissonance when someone is trying to marry opposing contrary views because they accept them to be true despite their glaring incompatibility. Also you’ve misread the texts you’re quoting like Col 1:15. Where does it say that Jesus was begotten at Creation? If anything else where it says Jesus was the Creator of Genesis 1 so He can’t be the begotten of the Father if He is doing the creating.

Answer (score 0):

*The water and light in Genesis 1:1-3*

**Short Answer**

The water can be found in Genesis1:2;

> *"and the darkness was without form or shape, with darkness over the abyss and a mighty wind sweeping over the waters*."(NAB)

As you can there was no creation yet as described, Jesus the Logos must be conceived first in the waters of the pure womb of a Woman mystically.

Now you also mentioned ***Proverbs8:22***, that is the Spirit of Created Wisdom and this is the First Act of God as it pertains to His Divine Plan. The spirit of Created Wisdom envelops the Alpha & Omega, meaning when God desires to create mankind to share His Infinite Glory in eternity, God had to first lay down His Divine Plan.

*Genesis1:1 and Genesis1:2 is the blueprint of God's Divine Plan in eternity.*

***Genesis1:1*** pertains to the ***"Way of the Cross"*** as revealed in the Hebrew word ***"Bereshit"*** look at the explanation below.

and ***Genesis1:2*** pertains to the ***"Mystery of Incarnation***", meaning after God had laid out the Divine Plan of Salvation, He then conceived how to incarnate the Logos and that is, it need to born of a Woman. That's why Genesis1:2 was described as the Spirit is hovering the waters or forming the Logos in the waters of the pure womb of a Woman.

Regarding your understanding about Jesus Christ the Begotten Son of God.Jesus Christ soul is a mystery, although it is a human soul the bible tells us it pre-existed in eternity in the bosom of the Father.

New American Standard Bible

> *No one has seen God at any time; the only begotten God who is in the bosom of the Father, He has explained Him.*(John1:18)

When we say bosom, Jesus substance is the same with the Father. That's why Jesus said;

> **"I and the Father are one.”** (John10:30)

and St.Paul tells to the Collossians what is the humanity of Jesus is as the Son of God;

> *"The Son is the image of the invisible God, the firstborn over all creation. "*

***Genesis1:1 is the Blueprint of God's Divine Plan for Salvation*** that reveals to us that God foreknew that Adam & Eve will fall to temptation and that the sending of Jesus to Redeem mankind is not because Adam & Eve committed the original sin but the Omnipotent God in desiring to share His Glory to created mankind has to conceive a Divine Plan how every human being can enter His Kingdom.

And Genesis1:1 revealed that there's only one way for mankind to enter the Glory of Heaven and that is what Jesus Christ humanity offers it's called the *"Way of the Cross".*

**Jesus in Genesis: 1. The First Word of the Bible**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmnUkNT55gU&t=1s
The video would tell us that God conceptualize first His Divine Plan and who are the Key Players to fulfill His Dream of having a created mankind achieve Theosis/Divination for it to be worthy to enter His Kingdom.
The Divine Plan is very simple "God will create a soul and the soul will need a human body to animate and that soul must return to God Divinized or Glorified, How?

The soul of man can only be Divinized/Theosis by embracing the only way, only one way that what's Jesus Christ had shown to all of mankind, that's why God the Father sent Him to show us the Way. What is the Way?

> **"THE WAY OF THE CROSS"** is the only way to enter God's Kingdom.

The Cross is the Wisdom of God as Jesus is the Wisdom of God.We cannot separate Jesus from the Cross.

Genesis1:1-2 is the blueprint of God's Divine Plan for the Salvation of Mankind, and God had created a spirit of Wisdom to envelop this whole plan. And that is the Spirit of Wisdom mentioned in Proverbs8:22.

But this kind of teaching need a lot of graces to understand that's why the Apostles said in scripture;

> *"Brothers, I could not address you as spiritual, but as worldly—as infants in Christ. 2I gave you milk, not solid food, for you were not yet ready for solid food. In fact, you are still not ready, 3for you are still worldly.*(1Corinthian3:1-3)

Hope this explanation shed light on your inquiry about the ***"waters"*** in ***Genesis1:2*** as we need the whole picture from the point of view of the Spirit of Created Wisdom to grasp the beautiful plan of God for all who will follow His Divine Will.

After *Genesis1:1 and Genesis1:2* had been written only then the creation time begins...***"Let there be Light*** was uttered as Jesus Christ is the LIGHT that was already formed mystically in the Eternal Now of the Abba Father.